# What are my errors in this c code I keep receiving an error message?

Tags: c

So I am beginning my project. Right now I am trying to make a header file and include it in the code. But I am not sure if I am doing it right.

Below is the project: I only included the part that I have worked up to as I do not want a completed project. I'm looking to understand.

Objective: Create a C script that will find the Zero-Input Response of a Second order Linear Time Invariant System D<sup>2</sup>y+a1Dy+a2 = 0 based on coefficients (a1 and a2) and initial conditions (y(0) and y’(0)).  (D=d/dt)

Requirements:

1. The user should be prompted to type in coefficients of the Linear System and two Initial Conditions: D<sup>2</sup>y+a1Dy+a2 = 0.
2. Find the roots of the second order nontrivial solution. D<sup>2</sup>y+a1Dy+a2 = 0 => λ<sup>2</sup>+a1λ+a2 = 0

Create a header file for this step.

The header file I created, `roots.h`:

```
#ifndef roots_h
#define roots_h

#include <stdio.h>

// Function Declaration
float posroot(float, float);
float negroot(float, float);

#endif /* roots_h */
```

roots.c:

```
#include <math.h>

int posroot(float a1, float a2){
    float root1;
    root1=(((-1)*(a1)) + sqrt((pow(a1,2)) - (4*a1*a2))) / (2);
    return root1;
}

#include <math.h>

int negroot(float a1, float a2){
    float root2;
    root2= (((-1)*(a1)) - sqrt( (pow(a1,2)) - (4*a1*a2))) / (2);
    return root2;
}
```

The main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "roots.h"//header file

int main(){
    //Variables
    float a1, a2, y0, dy0,root1, root2;

    //User asked to type in coeffecients
    printf("Enter a1 a2 y(0) and y'(0) seperated by a space: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f %f", &a1, &a2, &y0, &dy0);

    //Using the functions 
    root1=posroot(a1, a2);
    root2=negroot(a1, a2);

    //print the roots
    printf("The roots of the second order nontrivial solution: %f and %f", root1,root2);
    return 0;
}
```

On the header file, it keeps saying "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant".

Comment: what is the definition of `roots();`?

Comment: This code make no sense. `a1, a2, l1, l2` are all in global namespace after some function prototype for `Header`. If it doesn't even compile, chances are very strong  you're not "doing it right".

Comment: You need to decide whether your root-finding function is named `Header()` or `roots()`. (I'm guessing the latter.). And you need to decide whether to put the *definition* of this function (the code that actually does the work) into `main.c` or `roots.c` -- again, I'm guessing the latter.  (But it definitely doesn't belong in `roots.h`, which is where you seem to have it now.)

Comment: It's an online lecture and he only went over header files for about 3 minutes. I changed it to roots

Comment: Why doesn't it belong in the header file

Comment: Note that the specification implies that you need 4 input values, not just 2.  You need both `a1` and `a2` (which you do ask for), and also `y0` and `y'0` (initial value and derivative).  Having said that, I'm not sure how you're supposed to use those values.

Comment: *Why doesn't it belong in the header file*? There's a basic rule that only declarations go in header files -- what the type of a global variable is, what parameters a global function accepts and what types it returns.  But the actual *definitions* -- the initial values of any global variables, and the code ("body") making up functions -- go in `.c` files.  This should be explained in any good introduction of how to do multi-file programming in C, and if you haven't read one of those yet, I'm afraid you're going to have lots of confusion.

Comment: I read some info and I made some tweaks but I know I'm still wrong. Can you give it another look?

Comment: Any idea why you include `#include <math.h>` twice in `roots.c` (once before each function *definition*)? (once is enough). The key is you only need to include the headers that contain the function *prototypes* used by the functions *defined* in that source. See the answer by @Clifford below.

Comment: You have changed the code in the question such that the question no longer makes any sense, and any existing answer even less sense.  I would not expect the code now exhibited to produce the error message described.  Do not change questions on SO such they become fundamentally different.  If an answer or comment allows you to fix the original question, but you have further problems, post a new question.  SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Your question describes this as part of a "project", but it appears that in fact this is part of an a "assignment", which is a different matter.  I would be suspicious of your source material; phrases such as _"Create a C script..._, and _"Create a header file for this step."_, suggest that the author has little more understanding of C than you do.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of header files--they exist to ensure that different source (.c) files all agree on global things (variable types, etc.).

You appear to be attempting to put function code into your header.  The line

```
float Header( float l1, float l2);
```

is a forward declaration for a global routine Header that takes two parameters, both of which are floats.

But then you appear to be putting in what are supposed to be the contents of the Header() function, which ought to be in a .c file.  You are getting compile errors because you have a semicolon at the end of your declaration line.  The function ought to look something like

```
float Header( float l1, float l2)
{
    float a1, a2, return_value;
    float l1= (((-1)*(a1)) + sqrt( (pow(a1,2)) - (4*a1*a2))) / (2);
    float l2= (((-1)*(a1)) - sqrt( (pow(a1,2)) - (4*a1*a2))) / (2);
    return some_value;
}
```

This code is still wrong (is is referencing unassigned variables a1 and a2, and overwriting the passed-in variables l1 and l2.  And the return value is never assigned--presumably the intent is to do something with l1 and l2 and return the results.

If you correct these errors and get the Header() function working, it would actually compile if you #include'd it from a .h file into a .c file, but it would be an extremely bad idea.  It would mean that if two .c file both #include'd it, you would end up with a link error as there would be two instances of Header() defined.  The *only* time you should have a C function in a .h file is if you are declaring a `static inline` function.

---

Comments on your new code:

Your roots.h file looks fine.

The roots.c file should only `#include <math.h>` once.  It is safe to do it multiple times, as it has the #ifndef directives around it, but there is no reason to. You should also #include "roots.h" into it to guarantee that you are declaring your functions the way other files will be expecting you to.  In the code you give, you have an error in that posroot() and negroot() are defined as returning ints, but the roots.h file says they return floats.  With a #include of "roots.h", you would be guaranteed to get a compile error (which is what you want.  Without it, you would need to debug your code to figure out what was wrong).

The main.c file looks fine, although I don't understand why you are asking the user to input y0 and dy0 when you do not use them for anything.

Comment: so would I end up creating 2 header files one for each root

Comment: No, just the one.  See my comments above, added below my original comments

Comment: so when I tried to include #include "roots.h" into the root.c it gave me an error. It said the posroot() and negroot() had conflicting types. What do mean by the second part of your response. I thought I used float.

Comment: In roots.c, you have "int posroot(float a1, float a2){".  That ought to be "float posroot(float a1, float a2){"

Comment: Now it doesn't have an error message, but when I input anything it says nan for the roots. Is there something wrong with my equation

Comment: I suspect you will find that it is input-dependent.  You are calling sqrt() on (pow(a1,2) - 4 * a1 * a2).  If 4 * a1 * a2 > a1^2 then the term will be negative and sqrt() will return NAN.  (I just tested your code with the input "100 2 3 4" and I got numeric roots.)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare variable outside of a function, its initialiser expression must be one that can be evaluated at compile time.  That excludes any initialiser that invokes a function.

It seems likely that you intended the variables `l1` and `l2` to be *inside* a function. Little else about the header roots.h makes much sense in the context of the code in `main()`.

While you need a function *definition*, such a definition should not normally be placed in a header file (unless it is declared `inline` or `static` but that would be unusual and in non trivial applications can result in "code bloat" so it is not a habit you want to get into even for trivial code.
Header files are normally *declarative*; i.e. they declare symbols that are *defined* elsewhere.  You then use separate compilation and linking of individual translation units.

In this case you might have:

*roots.h*

```
#ifndef roots_h
#define roots_h

// Find the roots of the second order nontrivial solution
void roots( float a1, float a2, float* l1, float* l2 ) ;

#endif /* roots_h */
```

*roots.c*

```
#include <math.h>
#include "roots.h"

void roots( float a1, float a2, float* l1, float* l2 )
{
    float r = sqrt( a1*a1 - 4*a1*a2) ;
    *l1 = (-a1 + r) / 2 ;
    *l2 = (-a1 - r) / 2 ;
}
```

*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "roots.h"  //header file

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a1 and a2 separated by a space: ");
    float a1, a2;
    scanf("%f %f", &a1, &a2);

    float l1, l2;
    roots( a1, a2, &l1, &l2) ;

    printf( "l1 = %f, l2 = %f\n", l1, l2 ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

The you must *separately* compile both roots.c and main.c, then link the resulting object files. Most often you would manage separate compilation and linking via a makefile or an IDE project management - otherwise it becomes very tedious and error prone with even a small number of translation units.

For trivial code (I appreciate that this is part of a larger project), you might simply avoid that and place the code in a single file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void roots( float a1, float a2, float* l1, float* l2 )
{
    float r = sqrt( a1*a1 - 4*a1*a2) ;
    *l1 = (-a1 + r) / 2 ;
    *l2 = (-a1 - r) / 2 ;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a1 and a2 separated by a space: ");
    float a1, a2;
    scanf("%f %f", &a1, &a2);

    float l1, l2;
    roots( a1, a2, &l1, &l2) ;

    printf( "l1 = %f, l2 = %f\n", l1, l2 ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be really helpful to explain why you included no other headers in `roots.h` and included `math.h` and `roots.h` in `roots.c` and then include `stdio.h` and `roots.h` in `main.c`. From my read of the question, that seems to be a point of bewilderment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin possibly, but the OP has modified the question to apparently incorporate advice given in answers and comments such that the question is fundamentally changed and this answer now looks like nonsense - being an answer to a different question. On that basis I am not minded to develop this further; it is difficult to meaningfully answer a moving target question.

Comment: That kind of destroys the benefit of all prior comments and answers referring to the original content then. They shall remain confuzzled.